# Identifying a Specific Cable

Tags: cable, mobile-phone, charger

I've recently discovered an old mobile phone that I would like to power up, however, it is lacking in a charger. I was wondering if you could help me identify the type of cable I would need to use to charge it - and more specifically, whether it is a common cable used for lots of things or one specific to this mobile (if so, I will have to buy a charger for it, but I was hoping it would be a common cable.)

[image]

**Edit:** The phone is a Motorola mr201.

Comment: What model phone is it?

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that! It is a Motorola mr201.

Comment: It's probably a properietary connector. Few years ago it was very uncommon to use standarized charging sockets in mobile phones. (except for PDAs, which often had miniUSB sockets)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mobile phones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most older phones were a proprietary connection. Devices standardizing around micro, or even mini USB is a recent trend.

You best bet is to take the model of phone and Google: *charger for **brand+model**

[This claims to be the correct charger for the Motorola mr201](http://www.ebatts.com/motorola_mr201_cell-phone_accessories.aspx)

Comment: Shame, I was hoping I wouldn't have to go out and buy anything! Anyway, thank you very much.